# Regular expressions for phone number patterns

Tags: regex, oracle, pattern-matching

Do you know if is possible to transform a pattern like this to regular expressions:

ABCDXXXXYYYY

Where ABCDEFGH.. are consecutive numbers and V, X, Y, Z are any number.

The pattern above should match:

123400006666
456799994444
etc.

Please note that I'm not asking for a full solution, but some idea on how to approach this problem. Have you ever faced a situation like this before (to search a DB for defined patterns that doesn't seem to fit RegExps?

Any comment would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't identify consecutive numbers in a regular expression as they're too context dependant.

However, I think this would be easily possible in PL/SQL and possibly possible in SQL.

If you *only* want to use SQL then you can generate a string of consecutive numbers using a combination of [`connect by`](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html) and either the undocumented function [`wm_contact`](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm) or the user-defined function [`stragg`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402)

Something like:

```
 select replace(stragg(level),',','')
   from dual
connect by level <= 5
```

Concatenating this with a regular expression may get you close but I don't think that this is the way to go. I would definitely investigate using a PL/SQL function and possibly forgetting about regular expressions completely.

Doing the following will split out a number into an array, which you can then loop through and manipulate. As requested, this is just a starting point and you may want to change it around a lot. As there's no actual SQL and it's just string manipulation it's pretty efficient doing something like this.

```
create or replace function validate_phone( P_phone number ) 
                 return number is

   type t__phone is table of number index by binary_integer;
   t_phone t__phone;

   l_consecutive varchar2(150);

begin

   -- Test whether we actually have a number first ( code below ).
   if is_number(P_phone) = 0 then
       return null;
   end if;

   -- Split out the phone number into individual array elements.
   for i in 1 .. length(to_char(P_phone)) loop

      t_phone(i) := substr(to_char(P_phone, i, 1))

   end loop;

   for i in t_phone.first .. t_phone.last loop

      -- If we find a consecutive number then build this string.
      if t_phone.exists(i + 1)
        and t_phone(i) = t_phone(i + 1) - 1 then
         l_consecutive := l_consecutive || t_phone(i);
      end if;

   end loop;

   return something;

end validate_phone;
```

You may, as indicated in the above want to check whether your phone number is actually numeric first:

```
create or replace function is_number( P_number varchar2 ) 
        return number is

   /* Test a number to see whether it actually is one
      return a 1 / 0 rather than boolean so it can also
      be used in plain SQL.
      */

   l_number number;

begin

   l_number := P_number;

   return 1;

exception when others then
   return 0;
end is_number;
```

Answer (score 2):

The language you describe is not context-free (in case the length of the prefix consisting of consecutive numbers is arbitrary) and not a regular language, therefore can not be expressed by a regular expression.